# Creating a menu statement in Java from text file

Tags: java, arrays

I want to allow the user to select a text file which has different voting options within it, have the program read the file, and then create a menu from which the user can vote from those options and place the results in a separate document. I have the program reading the text file and showing the options in the output but I cannot figure out how to make it into a menu from which people can select. I know it has something to do with an array but the issue is the program is supposed to be designed so that regardless of the number of options in the text file the menu automatically changes.

***I edited the code and It is currently working. I assigned a variable called choice to store the user answer and display it to see if It was storing the user choice correctly and it seems to be. My next problem now is that the final goal of this assignment is to allow the user to vote as many times as they desire and then when the user indicates they are done to tally and display all the votes the user made. I know that i need to include a while loop to account for voting multiple times and a quit option. The thing i am having trouble with however is how to store all of the user choices and display them at the end since i only have one variable at this time called "choice". the part of the code i updated is now in place of the previous code. The results i get in NetBeans are below***

1: Republican
2: Democratic
3: Independent
Would you like to vote for:3
2
choice = 2
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 10 seconds)

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
// * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
//* and open the template in the editor.


  /**
  *
```

* @author 
   */
     public class SurveyMaker {

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
  public static void main(String[] args)  {
  JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
  Scanner in = null;
  List<String> myOptions = new ArrayList<String>();
  if(chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
  {
     File selectedFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();

     try{
     in = new Scanner(selectedFile);
     int lineNumber = 1;
     final int MAX_LINES = 9;

     while (in.hasNextLine() && lineNumber <= MAX_LINES)
     {
        String line = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println(lineNumber + ": " + line);
        myOptions.add(line);
        lineNumber++;
     }
         System.out.println("Would you like to vote for: " + myOptions.size());
         Scanner scanchoice = new Scanner(System.in);
         int choice = scanchoice.nextInt();
         System.out.println("choice = "+ choice);
     if (in.hasNextLine()) 
     {
         System.out.println("..."); 
     }

     }

     catch(FileNotFoundException ex)
     {
         System.out.println("There was an error with the file.  Try again.");
         System.exit(1);
     }
     catch(IOException ex)
     {
         System.out.println("There was an error with the file.  Try again.");
         System.exit(1);
     }
  }
  else {
      System.out.println("You didn't choose a file.");
      System.exit(0);
  }
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while (in.hasNextLine() && lineNumber <= MAX_LINES)
 {
    String line = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println(lineNumber + ": " + line);
    lineNumber++;
 }
```

Here's where you'll need to add logic. You already have code that fetches the lines individually now you just need to create a system that works with each of these. You're essentially breaking down the file into 1 line segments.

As mentioned in other answers, an `ArrayList` object can be used to store objects for later use. If you want to create an ArrayList and store Strings in it you'd declare it as such:

```
List<String> myOptions = new ArrayList<String>();
```

You can now use `myOptions` in your loop:

```
while (in.hasNextLine() && lineNumber <= MAX_LINES)
 {
    String line = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println(lineNumber + ": " + line);
    myOptions.add(line);
    lineNumber++;
 }
```

Now, whenever a user makes a selection the line number corresponds to the array index + 1. So if they wanted to select option 2, you could work with `myOptions.get(1)`. Or more generically `myOptions.get(selection - 1)` Just make sure you validate the user's selection to make sure you're not going out of bounds! (Tip: use `myOptions.size()`)

Comment: I am going to repost further below the new code. Could you look at it and see if this would work better?

Answer (score 0):

Create an `ArrayList` and add each line from the file into it.  If you want to make a text menu, that's as easy as printing each one out and asking the user to enter the number corresponding to their choice (with some validation of course).  If you wanted to make a GUI menu, that's a little more involved.